# How to avoid tiling when setting a view's backgroundColor?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I'm trying to set up a background image for my app, but the image is tiling. How do I prevent this? I want my image to fit to the background.

In CSS I would set `NO-REPEAT`; is there something like that?

I have tried this code:

```
-(IBAction)btnAddBackground
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
}
```

Comment: You have used a method that *explicitly* does tiling. The help for `initWithPatternImage` states: *During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.* What else have you considered?

Comment: could u please suggest something or can u just write the code i hope you have understood the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) makes a couple of suggestions for this:

> - Image-based backgrounds - For views that display relatively static content, consider using a `UIImageView` object with gesture recognizers instead of subclassing and drawing the image yourself. Alternatively, you can also use a generic `UIView` object and assign your image as the content of the view’s `CALayer` object.